# PHP Restore an Array from a String

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array which is very complicated to generate.

Hence, would like to generate it once and then store as a string in a database.

Then, whenever it is needed, it can be simply retrieved from the DB as a string and declared as an array. Is there an easy way to do such a thing on PHP **without using the eval() function**.

So the string in the db might be something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['none'] => Array
                (
                    ['none'] => Array
                        (
                            ['Page'] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 2
                                    [2] => 3
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['Volume 1'] => Array
                (
                    [] => Array
                        (
                            ['Page'] => Array
                                (
                                    [27] => 18
                                    [28] => 19
                                    [29] => 20
                                )

                        )

                )

            ['Volume 2'] => Array
                (
                    [] => Array
                        (
                            ['Page'] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 2
                                    [2] => 3
                                    [3] => 4
                                    [4] => 5
                                    [5] => 6
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, use serialize and unserialize functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) functions. They will serialize an array into a JSON string or deserialize a valid JSON string to an array respectively.

Using serialize/unserialize functions might not always be a good idea, because they come with security issues. Code might get executed upon deserialization which you had not intended. If no outside users have write access to the serialized objects, it should be fine though.

Comment: i just encoded and decoded. the function changed [0] => Array TO [0] => stdClass Object. i.e. the Array became stdClass Object. any idea how to get aorund this. I need it to stay an array.

Comment: thanks but seems to add alot of overhead which serialize does not.

Comment: Well, I prefer security over overhead. Serialize uses a binary format, and JSON is an ASCII based format (and shouldn't need any extra care when passed around between various architectures or PHP versions)